# Facebook Scheduled Posts and Twitter

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter

I linked my Facebook page and Twitter. When I post messages through API, they are getting posted to both my Facebook and Twitter.

However, it's not working when I try the **scheduled Facebook posts**. At the scheduled time, the Facebook post is getting posted, but it is not sending them to Twitter.

Is this a known problem?

Comment: I also have this problem

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem too, but unfortunately Google search gave me an answer that Facebook's scheduled post won't integrate with Twitter.

**Here is the link that I found (Read #5):**
http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/facebook-scheduled-posts/